# How can I refresh the Native Bounding Box

Tags: vector-layer, geowebcache, geoserver-rest-api

After add new Feature to VectorLayer, I want to refresh Native Bounding Box to seed tile caching. But I'm not found res API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See documentation about it, here:
https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/rest/api/featuretypes.html#recalculate