API REST import geoserver/rest/imports not creating Grid subset bounds
I'm using /geoserver/rest/imports/ to import a folder with shapefile (.shp .dbf .shx and .prj). It works well but the bounding boxes are dynamic. I need to calculate the Bounding Boxes like in the UI clicking "Compute from data"
{
    "import": {
        "targetWorkspace": {
            "workspace": {
                "name": "GIS"
            }
        },
        "data": {
            "type": "directory",
            "location": "/opt/geoserver_data/shapefiles/name"
        }
    }
}


I need that to be able to obtain all the layers using geoserver/gwc/rest/layers/{layerName} and if the bounds are calculated I get it in the response.
I searched everywhere but there is not enough documentation available.

see https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/424752/79

I found the issue. The coordinates from /geoserver/gwc/rest/layers/${name} are returned only if the layer is in the cache. I found a small fix calling geoserver/gwc/demo/${namespace}:${layer}?gridSet=EPSG:4326&format=application/vnd.mapbox-vector-tile that renders the layer and creates the cache. The issue is that this cache is lost after some time. Is there a way to force /geoserver/gwc/rest/layers/${name} to always return the coordinates?
